# OSX - ZSH - PATH - /usr/bin duplicated

Tags: macos, path, zsh

I need some help to understand why my path looks like the way it looks.

Issuing echo $PATH in zsh returns :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/bin
```

Now, let's have a closer look of the different parts :

```
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:
```

it comes from my .zprofile (Python 3 installation)

```
- /usr/bin/: 
- /bin: 
- /usr/sbin:
- /sbin:
- /usr/local/bin:
```

These parts come from my /etc/paths folder.

```
- /usr/X11/bin:
```

This part come from my etc/path.d folder

```
- /usr/local/go/bin:
```

This part was added during GO installation.

```
- /usr/bin
```

???

I have looked at -/etc/paths -.zshrc -.zprofile -.profile -/etc/profile -.zshenv. 
None of them sourced or added a second /user/bin neither to the PATH.

How can I remove the second /user/bin from my PATH if I don't know which file to edit?

Thank you.

Comment: You can have a look at what your shell does when it is launched: `zsh -x -i -c exit`. Or if you are only looking for path related issues: `zsh -x -i -c exit 2>&1 | grep -C 2 -i path`

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your time. I am to new to zsh and shell scripting to understand your two commands. I tested them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In ZSH, removing duplicates in the PATH variable is done via `typeset -U PATH` and not `typeset -u PATH`(the latter would just convert the content to uppercase..)

Comment: actually in the doc is 'path', not 'PATH'. https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24

Comment: It's because of the context. It's said _"The incantation `typeset -U path', where the -U stands for unique, tells the shell that it should not add anything to $path if it's there already"_ so if your path variable is named $PATH you should use uppercase. If you look a bit above you'll understand why they don't use uppercase right here.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't explain where the second `/usr/bin` comes from, you can put `typeset -u PATH` after the last place you append anything to $PATH. This will remove duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use zsh to enter the command `zsh` shell and then use `typeset -u PATH` to remove the duplicates. I have used small -u in typeset, but it has turned the variables into uppercase and hasnt removed the duplicates.